# Left align (to the page) displayed math

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

How can I left align the display math environment (either `$$` or `\[`)? I keep running into people asking about the `align` environment; but I just want to change displayed math from center to left align relative to the page.

Comment: I saw that style in a book and like it, since I did not have to look all over the page width for the formulas, but found them on the left side as well. Is there something I should keep in mind, when I use this style?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `flalign` from the `amsmath` package:

[image]

### Note:

- The `showframe` package was used just to be able to see where the text is relative to the page margins.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
e & = mc ^2 &\\%  Note the trailing & which is required to equations to the left
F & = ma
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively, if you want **all** equations left aligned, you can use the package option `fleqn` as in `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` which will align them *towards* the left.  The indentation is controlled by `\mathindent`, so you could use `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` if you wanted to eliminate that.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
e & = mc ^2 \\
F & = ma
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get it - that's exactly what OP said he wants to avoid in question: *I keep running into people asking about the align environment; but I just want to change displayed math from center to left align relative to the page.* I think he means to align all displaymath (using `$$`) left. I know this thread is old, but that's what I was looking for when entered this page through google.

Comment: @trakos: I am not sure what you mean. The OP wanted to "left align the display math environment", which is what this answer does.  I suggest you post a new question detailing what you want, and you can reference this question if it is relevant.  Please do include a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: for some reason the first solution in this answer doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Perhaps you should note in your answer the importance of & in first case. I had to wrap my formula in ampersands for this to work. You do have a comment about trailing & but you don't mention that it's required to have & before the expression as well.

Comment: @dKab: The first `&` is needed to get the `=` to align. If this question gets edited in the future I will add that note.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the current accepted answer doesn't exactly answer the question (OP stated either `$$` or `\[` and not the `align` environment because he already found a solution for that).

Here is a solution with `\[ ... \]` (doesn't work with `$$...$$` though):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent Here is some left-aligned math:
\[x^2+1\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` is sticky (it will affect the entire remainder of the document, unless you later reset it. I am not even sure that you can use `\setlength{\mathindent}` mid document to reset it. Is there someway to left-align a single block of `displaymath` without affecting any of the other blocks of `displaymath`? One equation becomes left-aligned; all others are centered?