# Put formulas on the left position in LateX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left align (to the page) displayed math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53773/left-align-to-the-page-displayed-math)

As you know the following equation will be in the center:

```
$$
\sum_{\substack{a\leq1/2\\0<b\leq T}}\frac{2+a}{2|b|}
$$
```

And the following is on the left but in small size and decrease the space:

```
$
\sum_{\substack{a\leq1/2\\0<b\leq T}}\frac{2+a}{2|b|}
$
```

But the below formula is similar to the first one, but on the left:

```
$
\displaystyle{\sum_{\substack{a\leq1/2\\0<b\leq T}}\frac{2+a}{2|b|}}
$
```

Does anyone know another way such that it works similar to the last one (put the formula on the left) but with:

```
\begin{xxxx}
*
\end{xxxx}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left align (to the page) displayed math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53773/5764).

Comment: Also see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `flalign*` environment from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to put equations flush with the left hand side:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  \sum_{\substack{a\leq1/2\\0<b\leq T}}\frac{2+a}{2|b|} &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}​
```

The extra alignment characters `&&` is required. The [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) is merely to highlight the text block boundary and not needed in your final document.

Answer (score 1):

By passing the `fleqn` option to your document class, you can achieve that display style math is moved to the left instead of being centered.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\begin{document}
    \[ \sum_{a\leq1/2}\frac{2+a}{2|b|} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In combination with `fleqn`, you can use `\mathindent` to specify the indentation e.g. `\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}`.