# Flush left equations in beamer column

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, equations

When I do this in `beamer`:

```
\begin{column}[T]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
F = m a
\end{equation}

This is Newton's law.
\end{column}
```

the equation sits in the center of the column while the text is flushed left.
How do I make both flush left?

Comment: Use `\documentclass[fleqn]{beamer}` and set the `\mathindent` length to `0pt`, as suggested in [Left align (to the page) displayed math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53773/5764).